# C++ function switch on value

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated function

```
template <typename S, typename T>
string DoStuff(const S& s, const T& t, const string& format) {
    ...
}
```

But `format` changes the function's behaviour completely (imagine values like "csv", "json", etc.).  So it would make a bit more sense to have separate functions.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, that this should be possible with some sort of specialisation.  Otherwise, I just have to add a dispatch function, which would work but feels like I've missed something obvious.

```
template <typename S, typename T>
string DoStuff(const S& s, const T& t, const string& format) {
    if (format == "csv")
        return DoStuffCSV(s, t);
    if (format == "json")
        return DoStuffJSON(s, t);
    // ...
}

template <typename S, typename T>
string DoStuffCSV(const S& s, const T& t) {
...
}

template <typename S, typename T>
string DoStuffJSON(const S& s, const T& t) {
...
}
```

Conceptually, I want this (which of course doesn't work)

```
template <typename S, typename T, string("csv")>
string DoStuff(const S& s, const T& t) {
...
}

template <typename S, typename T, string("json")>
string DoStuff(const S& s, const T& t) {
...
}
```

Comment: does it have it to be a runtime string? Or can it be an enum or a tag?

Comment: You should be able to do this with an `enum`

Comment: If you have to make a decision anyways in your caller why not directly DoStuffJSON or DoStuffCSV or better yet use function pointer if decision is to make just once and call the same function multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @bolov and @Nathan Oliver write, you can do this with an enum.

To branch at compile time, I'd add [`std::integral_constant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant):

```
#include <type_traits>                                                                                                                                                                                   

enum class type
{   
    txt = 1,
    cst = 2,
};  

using txt_specifier = std::integral_constant<type, type::txt>;
using csv_specifier = std::integral_constant<type, type::csv>;
```

The latter two are *types*, and you can overload on them at compile time (and using the numeric values, do fancy metaprogramming things if needed further).

Comment: You don't necessarily need types here, you can specialize by the enum value itself.

Comment: It might work with enums directly as @YamMarcovic notes, but I admit I am more easily able to wrap my head around using types to trigger polymorphism.  Thanks!

Comment: Acutally, @YamMarcovic I appreciate the comment, but I disagree. You can overload on types, not values. (Keep the upvote for the classiness, though :-) )

Comment: @AmiTavory Thanks :) But just for the record, you can: http://rextester.com/CIBJ50287

Comment: @AmiTavory Though I just noticed you used the word "overload" whereas I said "specialize"--two different things.

Comment: @YamMarcovic Oh, got it. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @AmiTavory My pleasure. :)

Comment: @AmiTavory Nice, thanks for the snippet.  And that example highlights nicely why this doesn't work with strings.

Answer (score 3):

So long as you want to depend on a value that can only be determined at run time, you're not missing anything: compile-time specialization is simply impossible.

However, as suggested by commenters, you *can* specialize according to a value that's known at compile-time, like an enum.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the correct code with a run-time value, you probably need some sort of despatch table:

```
const auto dispatch = []{
    std::map<std::string,std::function<string(const S&,const T&)>> table;
    table("csv") = [](const S& s,const T& t) { return do_stuff_csv(s,t); };
    table("json") = [](const S& s,const T& t) { return do_stuff_json(s,t); };
    return table;
}();
```

It's an exercise for the reader to generalise this sufficiently, and to take care of validating the `format` parameter...